# Using python to find even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ..

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms. 
This is how I am doing it, but I am getting the wrong value, and I am not sure why.

```
Sum=0
n=0
a=1
b=2
while a<=4e6 and b<=4e6:
    if a%2==0:
        Sum = Sum + a
    n=a+b
    a=b
    b=n
if b%2==0:
    sum=sum+b
print(Sum)
```

My value is 1089154 which is incorrect.

Comment: `if b %2 == 0:` is indented improperly, which makes it outside of the `while` loop. Is it that way in your code too?

Comment: Based on my answer below, I figured out your issue is your `while` statement should just be: `while a<=4e6:`

Comment: I.e. you want it to add `a` to `Sum` when `b` is more than 4m but `a` isn't

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica If you put it inside the loop, then you add even numbers to the sum twice. No good. Looks like an attempt to get a potential last even number and thus it *belongs* outside the loop.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Just making sure that it was what the OP intended. Wasn't sure if they were expecting it to be part of the loop or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by writing a function to get the fibonacci sequence elements up to the target number so you can more easily debug.

The `fibonacci` function returns a list of all elements in the fibonnaci sequence which are less to or equal to `n`:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    seq = [0, 1]
    while seq[-1] < n:
        seq.append(seq[-2] + seq[-1])
    return seq[:-1]
```

Then you can do a simple list comprehension to sum all the even items:

```
sum([i for i in fibonacci(4e6) if i%2 ==0])
```

Comment: The result I get is 4613732, which is exactly 3524578 more than your result. So the issue with your code seems to be that it is not adding the final element that meets the criteria of being below 4m to the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Fibonacci numbers start with 0 and 1, not 1 and 2. This won't affect your result, but it does make handling the numbers easier.

Start by writing a generator function that yields *all* the Fibonacci numbers (eventually).

```
def fib():
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

You don't have to test a value if it is even, because the even numbers appear very predictably in the sequence:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 ...
```

Starting with the first value, every third value is even.

Given the generator

```
f = fib()  # All the Fibonacci numbers
```

you can then get your answer in three easy steps:

```
from itertools import islice, takewhile

evens = islice(f, 0, None, 3)  # All the even Fibonacci numbers
small = takewhile(lambda x: x <= 4000000, evens)  # Just the ones under 4,000,000
result = sum(small)
```

You don't *need* the every-third-value trick, but it's a bit more efficient than

```
evens = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the minimal amount of changes to your code:

```
Sum=0
n=0
a=1
b=2
# while a<=4e6 and b<=4e6:
while a<=4e6:
    if a%2==0:
        Sum = Sum + a
    n=a+b
    a=b
    b=n
# if b%2==0:
#     sum=sum+b  
print(Sum)
```

Essentially you don't need to look at `b` because `b` is the *next* term.  If you stop the loop when `b` exceeds `4e6` you skip the value of `a` that is less than `4e6`.  Your if-statement after the loop tries to compensate for this, but it should have looked at `a` (if you had kept the while-statement the same) and it adds to `sum` not `Sum`.  You don't need that second if-statement since the while-statement is fixed.

I would have done it this way:

```
def fib(max=-1):
    curr, next = 0, 1
    while curr <= max:
        yield curr
        curr, next = next, curr + next

print(sum(n for n in fib(4e6) if n % 2 == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 0
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 4e6:
    if b % 2:
        s += b
    a, b = b, a + b

print(s)
```